# How to write Cron with php?

Tags: php, cron

```
<?php

class Baddriver{
// Constructor - open DB connection
function __construct() {
    $this->db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "dbname");
    $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
}
 // Destructor - close DB connection
function __destruct() {
    $this->db->close();
}

// Main method to redeem a code
function bad() {
    if(isset($_POST["plakano"]) || isset($_POST["secim"]) || isset($_POST["sehir"])){
    $sehir=$_POST["sehir"];
    $plakano=$_POST["plakano"];  
    $aciklama=$_POST["aciklama"];
    $secim=$_POST["secim"];
    $plaka = str_replace(",","",$plakano); 

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO veri (plakano,aciklama,tarih,sehir,secim) VALUES (?, ?, CURDATE(),?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $plakano,$aciklama,$sehir,$secim);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $this->db->commit();
    }
}

}

$api = new Baddriver;
$api->bad();
?>
```

This is my php file i search for 2 days now i understand 2 things first is i need to put

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
```

at the top (honestly don't know why) and i need to connect to my webserver open the shell and write the cron code like

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/user1/bin
MAILTO=user1@nowhere.org,user2@somewhere.org
0 2 1-10 * * du -h --max-depth=1 /
```

is it all than cron will work or something that i am missing? thanks for patiance and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/php -q` tells your server that this script should be run with php.

The cron code which you add to crontab will run your script at the specified intervals.

But that's not all. Your script uses $_POST, but you cannot post to a PHP script if you run it as a cron job. So those values won't be available.

Comment: first thanks for your answer and for explanation about the code so i need to connect to webserver and use the cron code and i need to delete $_POST variables thanks again mate.

Answer (score 2):

Cron is a tool to run command line tools on a schedule.  As such, a php script just needs to be written in a way that it doesn't require any functions of the web server.  ie: setheaders, $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE

The `#!/usr/bin/php -q` is if you make your script executable and run it directly from the command line, it hints at how to run it.  In this case 'use php in /usr/bin with the option "-q"'

The -q tells the script to run 'quiet', and avoids printing some http headers.

Also, see `man 5 crontab` for more details about the formatting of a crontab entry.

You can skip setting the script executable, and the #! line if you use `/usr/bin/php -q badDriver.php` at the end of your crontab entry.

```
53 23 * * 7 www-data /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/script/badDriver.php
```

Would run the script, as user 'www-data', every Sunday at 11:53pm server time.